# Unable to display dropdown and popover AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, popover

I am new to this, can you help me figure out why my dropdown is not displaying properly and also the popover of the second value of dropdown is not working properly?
I am a bit confuse since it is my first time trying this.
Here is my code

```
<ul class="nav site-nav">
<li class=flyout>
    <a href=#>Menu</a>

<!-- Flyout -->
<ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
  <li>
    <div ng-app>
      <div ng-controller="popoverCtrl">
        <a href="#" ng-mouseover="showPopover=true;" ng-mouseleave="showPopover=false;">Real Account <div class="popover" ng-show="showPopover"><span>{{ popover.title }}</span>{{ popover.message }}</div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div ng-app>
      <div ng-controller="popoverCtrl2">
        <a href="#" ng-mouseover="showPopover2=true;" ng-mouseleave="showPopover2=false;">Practice Account <div class="popover2" ng-show="showPopover2"><span>{{ popover2.title }}</span>{{ popover2.message }}</div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>
```

and my JS

```
function popoverCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.showPopover = false;

  $scope.popover = {
    title: 'Title',
    message: 'Message'
  };

}

function popoverCtrl2($scope2) {

  $scope2.showPopover2 = false;

  $scope2.popover2 = {
    title: 'Test',
    message: 'Sample'
  };
}
```

**Here is what I have done so far http://jsfiddle.net/fn1aj1e6/**

Comment: Are you declaring angular in the beginning of your code? Example: var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct below things in your code :

1. define only 1 `ng-app`, to the root most HTML element.(in your code `<ul>` tag but ideally `<html>` tag)
2. Remove `$scope2` from second controller., it should be only `$scope`.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ah8z7o7z/)

Comment: thank you but can you tell me why the dropdown overlaps ? is this related now with the css ?

Comment: @giogio : yes , `css` needs to be corrected. See this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckse0rdg/) with demo css.(just added a `margin-top` ., hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create the module using the AngularJS function `angular.module`. For example:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('app', []);

    myApp.controller('YourController', function ($scope) {
        //Your code
    });
```

Then in the HTML do it as,

```
    <div ng-app="app">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `function popoverCtrl2($scope2)`, as Angular will parse the argument names for dependency injection, and it will not find a service with name `$scope2`. Just use:

```
function popoverCtrl2($scope) {

  $scope.showPopover2 = false;

  $scope.popover2 = {
    title: 'Test',
    message: 'Sample'
  };

}
```